# MYSQL query not work propely

Tags: mysql, database

I have a problem with a query.I have two tables, one with clicks and one with conversions as follow

Table: **Conversion**

```
 id | ref id      | registered | tempo     | prod_cod
    ----------------------------
    1  |      1      | 04/05/2018 | 15385950 | oggn-1
    2  |      1      | 05/05/2018 | 15385950 | oggn-1
    3  |      1      | 06/05/2018 | 15385950 | oggn-1
```

Table: **Clicks**

```
 id    | ref id      | registered | tempo    | prod_cod | ip        | user_agent 
    ----------------------------
    1  |      1      | 05/05/2018 | 15385950 | oggn-1   | 192.168.1 | Mozilla....
    2  |      1      | 06/05/2018 | 15385950 | oggn-1   | 192.168.1 | Mozilla....
    3  |      1      | 07/05/2018 | 15385950 | oggn-1   | 192.168.1 | Mozilla....
```

I want a result selected by ref id of last seven days is:

Table: **result**

```
 registered    | clicks      | conversion
    ----------------------------
    04/05/2018 |      0      |  1
    05/05/2018 |      1      |  1
    06/05/2018 |      1      |  1
    07/05/2018 |      1      |  0
```

This is my query but it does not work well, because if in both databases is not present the registered value does not give all the results.

```
SELECT tbl_affiliate_traffic.registered, 
       Count(DISTINCT tbl_affiliate_traffic.id)    AS tarffic, 
       Count(DISTINCT tbl_affiliate_conversion.id) AS conversion 
FROM   tbl_affiliate_traffic CROSS 
       JOIN tbl_affiliate_conversion 
         ON tbl_affiliate_conversion.tempo >= '1524891602' 
            AND tbl_affiliate_conversion.registered = 
                tbl_affiliate_traffic.registered 
            AND tbl_affiliate_conversion.ref_id = '1' 
WHERE  tbl_affiliate_traffic.tempo >= '1524891602' 
       AND tbl_affiliate_traffic.ref_id = '1' 
GROUP  BY registered
```

Comment: What is the relational structure, i.e. what column(s) make up a unique key on each table, and which of these two tables is the 'master'? I am concerned that the join you have given might return too many values. It will return too few if you use JOIN where LEFT JOIN would be better, but I think we need to be clear about the structure before we get that far.

Comment: my problem is that there is not a master I have these two tables with elements in common and I would like to count the clikcs and the conversions grouped for days, I'm not good with the database management, that query written above is an attempt that has me brought to a partial solution

Answer (score 0):

You can't slow this problem in a single query if it possible slove, it takes too much time in the higher amount of data. use tow queries for this kind of scenario and array re-transform.

Query 1:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS _count,registered FROM `Conversion` GROUP BY registered
```

after executing this query you need to populate array like this

$Conversion = ['04/05/2018'=>1,'05/05/2018'=>1]

Query 2:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS _count,registered FROM `Clicks` GROUP BY registered
```

and populate array "Clicks" like this

$Clicks = ['04/05/2018'=>0,'05/05/2018'=>1]

after that, you can merge this tow arrays

```
foreach($Conversion as $key=>$val){$result[$key]['Conversion'] =  $val}
foreach($Clicks as $key=>$val){$result[$key]['Clicks'] =  $val}
```

Finally, you can get the result.